# R parallel computation with foreach for multiple output by different operation

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I'd like to use `foreach` to increase the computation speed. What I want to do is to output two results from single foreach loop.

Following is the simplified version of the original idea:

```
output <- list(matrix_addition = matrix(0, nrow = 2, ncol = 2), process_list = list())

for(i in c(1:10)){
  # value_1 indicates some calculation to get the matrix
  value_1 <- i * 2

  # value_2 indicates some calculation to process_list for each i
  value_2 <- i / 2

  output$matrix_addition <- output$matrix_addition + matrix(value_1, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
  output$process_list <- append(output$process_list, value_2)
}
```

The expected `output` will be like:

```
$matrix_addition
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  110  110
[2,]  110  110
```

and

```
$process_list
$process_list[[1]]
[1] 0.5

$process_list[[2]]
[1] 1

...

$process_list[[10]]
[1] 5
```

I tried to use `foreach` with `.combine = "+"` for the matrix addition part, but when it comes to multiple output, `mapply` seems not able to combine with `"+"`. I found several codes online with same operation for both outputs by using `.combine = "cbind", .multicombine=TRUE`. When it comes to different operation for two outputs, is there any way to do it?

Thanks for the help!

***edit:***

My `foreach` code for only matrix addition is

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

cl <- makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cl)

output <- foreach(i = 1:10, .combine = "+") %dopar% {
  value_1 <- i * 2
  matrix <- matrix(value_1, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
}

stopCluster(cl)
```

And my first attempt for the two output is

```
output <- foreach(i = 1:10) %dopar% {
  if(exists("temp") == FALSE) {
    output <- list(matrix_addition = matrix(0, nrow = 2, ncol = 2), process_list = list())
  }

  value_1 <- i * 2
  value_2 <- i / 2

  output$matrix_addition <- output$matrix_addition + matrix(value_1, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
  output$process_list <- append(output$process_list, value_2)
  output
}
```

It seems that the original `for` loop idea can't directly use in `foreach`.

Next, I found these codes online, it looks like:

```
comb <- function(...) {
  mapply("cbind", ..., SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
}

output <- foreach(i = 1:10, .combine="comb", .multicombine = TRUE) %dopar% {
  value_1 <- i * 2
  value_2 <- i / 2

  matrix_addition_part  <- matrix(value_1, nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
  process_list_part     <- value_2
  list(matrix_addition_part, process_list_part)
}
```

and

```
comb <- function(x, ...) {
  lapply(seq_along(x),
         function(i){c(x[[i]], lapply(list(...), function(y) y[[i]]))})
}

output <- foreach(i=1:10, .combine="comb", .multicombine=TRUE, .init=list(list(), list())) %dopar% {
  value_1 <- i * 2
  value_2 <- i / 2

  list(matrix(value_1, nrow = 2, ncol = 2), value_2)
}
```

These two are similar, the idea here is to save all matrix in the matrix addition part, and after `foreach`, matrix can be then add up. But the problem for me is that each matrix in my code is too big, which requires huge space to store, therefore I can't save all the matrix. I think I need to replace `"cbind"` in matrix addition part into something like `"+"`, but it doesn't work in `mapply`.

My guess is that I need to make the function `comp` contains both `"+"` and `"append"`, but still can't come up with a proper solution by utilizing `apply`.

Comment: Can you show your code for `foreach`

Comment: I add several `foreach` attempts of mine above.

Comment: Please look for "[r] foreach multiple" in SO. This has been answered several times already. You have basically two solutions: either you make a custom `.combine` function, or you just output a list and combine results afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for the help, just figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Just figure out how to do it:

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cl)

comb <- function(List1, List2) {
  output_a <- apply(abind(List1[[1]], List2[[1]], along = 3), 1:2, sum)
  output_b <- c(List1[[2]], List2[[2]])
  return(list(matrix_addition = output_a, process_list = output_b))
}

output <- foreach(i = 1:10, .combine = "comb", .init=list(matrix(0, 2, 2), list())) %dopar% {
  value_1 <- i * 2
  value_2 <- i / 2

  list(matrix_addition = matrix(value_1, nrow = 2, ncol = 2), process_list = value_2)
}

stopCluster(cl)
```

Here, by customizing the `.combine` function `comb`, separate the matrix addition part and process list part, and merge them into a list. Also, the first input (`List1` here) for the `comp` function will be `.init` or previous loop iteration (i-1) result, and second input (`List2` here) will be the current loop iteration (i) result.